# google pagespeed service returns 503 hovewer site is online

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have strange problem, cause I don't know how to get background request

I have newly updated site "whitestudio.org", and trying to test in the mentioned above service. Hovewer, google return me 503 response message. Don't know what to do.

Also, tried to test from command line, tested with success. Can anyone help me?

```
curl -H "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GoogleBot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.htm)" whitestudio.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way pagespeed bot header for mobile is

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Version/8.0 Mobile/12F70 Safari/600.1.4

(Wrote for those who want to test in future).

And that error was related to incorrect configured "A" record [DNS configuration - We migrated from one host to another.